# The Question of the Seven Barbies

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

<sup>[This question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124877/13-man-12-man-cartoon-puzzle) reminded me of this brainteaser I first saw, in an extended format, in a mystery manga from my younger days.</sup>

I bought my young niece a seven-pack of Barbies for Christmas.  (Okay, they might have been discount-store Julies rather than Mattel-brand Barbies, but hey, they're almost as good, right?)  I couldn't be at my sibling's house on the 25th, so I sent the box along and she opened it on Christmas morning.  However, I may have forgotten how rough my niece can get with her toys...

I arrived at my sibling's house today, and when I got to my niece's room, faced a veritable doll abattoir.  My niece had dismantled and dismembered her gifts, mutilating the poor Barbies beyond recognition and removing parts entirely:

> One Barbie had its left arm pulled off with such elan that the whole shoulder and neck assembly must have come with it, leaving its head disconnected from what remained of its torso.

> Another Barbie had its right arm removed similarly, with Barbie's whole shapely plastic chest removed with it.  Its lower torso and legs were now completely separated from its left arm, shoulder, and head.

> Two Barbies had one leg each pulled out from their socket--one left, one right.  I guess my niece likes symmetry.

> One Barbie had her whole midriff surgically removed--my sibling should probably keep the X-Acto knives better hidden.

> My niece must have continued her hobby-knife massacre, as the next Barbie had gotten her anatomically-incorrect hips removed. At least I found this doll's legs.

> And, naturally, one Barbie simply had its head pulled off.  I suppose the decapitation of Barbies is a time-honored tradition.

Although I couldn't find the removed pieces, all seven dolls were, more or less, accounted for.  It seems my niece has wholly demolished every doll I gave her...and may even be going around playing with some horrifying, Krazy Glued-together FrankenBarbie.  I'll need to buy her another gift.

***Or will I?***

Comment: Would those list items be better suited for list formatting, as opposed to quotation formatting? `-` instead of `>`, I mean

Comment: Sounds like your niece had taken a lesson from [another Barbie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaus_Barbie).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your niece was obviously re-enacting

> The Tokyo Zodiac Murders

or

> Young Kindaichi's Ijinkan Village / Western-style Village / The Mummy's Curse

> Those are actually the bodies of six dolls; one doll is complete.
>  The legs from doll 6 actually go with dolls 3 and 4.
>  The lower body of doll 4 actually goes with the upper body of doll 5.
>  The lower torso of doll 2 goes with upper body of doll 4.
>  Right torso and lower body of doll 1 go with upper body of doll 2.
>  Doll 7 goes with head of doll 1.
>  Leaving one intact doll.

Comment: Not surprised that the manga I read this in cribbed it from a novel.  Well put.